# Warning: openlog() has been disabled for security reasons in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have upgraded magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.0 using composer, now when i run any command in SSH it throws an error and can not execute it:

> openlog() has been disabled for security reasons

Comment: does your magento frontend and backend works fine?

Comment: No its 500 error

Answer (score 2):

I solve this error by changing php version for 2.3.0, because magento2.3.0 supports php version 7.2.

check your php version of cli by command

```
php -v
```

If it is not 7.2 then change it by these command

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

check your php version of apache on localhost/phpinfo.php

If it is not 7.2 then change it by these commands

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0 //7.0 is your old version
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

Comment: i will try both 7.1 and 7.2 php version but still warning comes...

Comment: Try this if it solves your problem
https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Extensions/Warning-syslog-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons/td-p/115400

Answer (score 2):

I had this using php 7.2 and it was because of my php configuration.  Check that your configuration hasn't disabled these methods (hence the warning).

Check your php.ini configuration file - I used phpinfo.php to check to make sure which installation I was using and what/where the configuration file in question is.

Check the "disable_function" entry and make sure openlog and syslog are **not** in there. If there, then remove them.

For example mine was...

**from**

disable_functions = "system,system_exec,symlink,shell,shell_exec,exec,passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close,proc_open,ini_alter,dl,show_source,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_terminate,highlight_file,define_syslog_variables,posix_uname,posix_getpwuid,apache_child_terminate,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,ini_restore,inject_code,**syslog,openlog**,define_syslog_variables,apache_setenv,eval,phpAds_XmlRpc,phpAds_remoteInfo,phpAds_xmlrpcEncode,phpAds_xmlrpcDecode,xmlrpc_entity_decode"

**to**

disable_functions = "system,system_exec,symlink,shell,shell_exec,exec,passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close,proc_open,ini_alter,dl,show_source,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_terminate,highlight_file,define_syslog_variables,posix_uname,posix_getpwuid,apache_child_terminate,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,ini_restore,inject_code,define_syslog_variables,apache_setenv,eval,phpAds_XmlRpc,phpAds_remoteInfo,phpAds_xmlrpcEncode,phpAds_xmlrpcDecode,xmlrpc_entity_decode"